# How to set multiple IP Address on a raspberry pi 3

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3, ethernet

I brought a USB to Ethernet adapter, now I connected that to USB on raspberry pi 3 on one end and to the ethernet on the other end (So that I can set two IP address for my pi).

***Note: I am also using my Ethernet port on Raspberry Pi 3***

If I disconnect my Ethernet port and connect only through USB to Ethernet Adapter, I couldn't communicate. I assume that there is no communication happening with my USB-Ethernet Adapter. I want both the IP addresses work at a time

Then I've changed the **/etc/network/interfaces** file as shown below:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.147.146
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.147.255

auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
address 192.168.147.145
netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

**This is my output from ifconfig  from the terminal:**

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:0d:2b:28  
      inet addr:192.168.147.146  Bcast:192.168.147.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:71565 errors:0 dropped:928 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:17901546 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:6283723 (5.9 MiB)  TX bytes:1220265483 (1.1 GiB)

eth0:0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:0d:2b:28  
      inet addr:192.168.147.145  Bcast:192.168.147.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:910 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:79976 (78.1 KiB)  TX bytes:79976 (78.1 KiB)
```

Please let me know your suggestions.....

Comment: Voted to close - not a programming question.

Comment: What do you need the multiple IP addresses for? Depending on your needs, you don't necessarily need another adaptor for that, since you can assign many different addresses to the same network adaptor. Also, Raspberry Pi 3 has WiFi built in, so that could also help you out maybe.

Comment: Looking for clarity on this as well.  Is this in regards to making your raspberry function as a VPN wireless access point?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your USB to Ethernet adaptor is a physical network adaptor however you have set it up as if it were a virtual network adaptor.

Try changing eth0:0 to eth1 in your /etc/network/interfaces file

Your code should look something like this:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.147.146
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.147.255

auto eth1
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.147.145
netmask 255.255.255.0

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

allow-hotplug wlan1
iface wlan1 inet manual
wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```